# Element following mouse lagging in next.js 13 app directory

Tags: next.js, framer-motion, next.js13

I am trying to add an element that follows the mouse around when I move the pointer.
I am using framer motion for the animation and have used an example from their docs as a base:
[Example from framer motion](https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-spring-transition-e6c8dm?from-embed=&file=/src/App.tsx:388-457)

When i added it to my Next.js 13 website, where I use the new app directory it becomes very laggy.
[Example from my code](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/jolly-water-ye94c6?file=%2Fapp%2Fpage.tsx&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A14%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A1%2C%22startColumn%22%3A14%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A1%7D%5D)

I figured something is probably wrong with my implementation, so I tried adding it to another Next.js 13 website, that doesn't use the app directory, and that worked without any issues.

So the problem seems to have something to do with the new app directory.

Do I need to Implement this in another way when using the app directory?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a fix, per se, however you don't need framer to do this. You can change the div to take in the x and y and transform on this. If you want to add a nice transition you can use a [cubic](https://cubic-bezier.com/#.17,.67,.83,.67).

For example, remove the `translate` from the CSS and leave the `top` and `right` to `0`.

Then make the div take in the x,y in the `style` like so

```
<div
   ref={ref}
   className="mousefollow"
   style={{
     transform: `translate(${x}px, ${y}px)`,
   }}/>
```

[Codepen](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/crimson-framework-5burio?file=%2Fapp%2Fglobals.css&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A36%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A13%2C%22startColumn%22%3A36%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A13%7D%5D)

Comment: Thanks, this works fine for sticking the following element to the cursor, but when I add a transition the lag is still there. Did you manage to make it work with a transition without lag?

Comment: I updated the codepen above. I've tried with and without a transition and it feels pretty smooth to be.

Comment: Ok, yeah that works as an alternative solution. Thank you!

Comment: Awesome @JoelUdd I am still interested in by Framer was lagging on 13 AppDir, but this solution imo is a little better because it doesn't require another package.